# mate-panel --reset command not found

Tags: ubuntu, mate-desktop

After some updates, our Ubuntu 14 MATE desktop doesn't have a panel, nor does it load a terminal.  After pressing ctrl+alt+f1, and logging into our account, I tried the command:

```
mate-panel --reset
```

But it says command not found.  We think this will fix our problem as described here:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=124839

But why it is saying mate-panel command not found?

Comment: That file is owned by 'mate-panel' package. Check if you've that package on your system.

Comment: I'd have to check this through the command line given most functionality on my system is broken.  `apt-get install mate-panel`?  I'm pretty sure that didn't work

Answer (score 4):

```
mate-panel --replace &
```

worked for me

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, it worked for me

Comment: You could add a `disown` to it so you can close the terminal again.